# Asymptotic distribution of the MLE of $\theta$ such that $\log X_i$ is distributed as $N(\theta, \theta)$

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be a random sample such that $\log X_i$ is distributed as $N(θ, θ),$  $θ > 0$ is unknown.

I've calculated the MLE and I got $$\hat\theta = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2}}{2} $$ where $Y_i = \log X_i$ for $i = 1, ..., n$.

I was wondering what the asymptotic distribution for this MLE would be as $n \rightarrow \infty$ . I've double-checked this MLE and I'm almost certain it is correct but I don't recognise this distribution nor what the sample mean looks like. I've tried the central limit theorem but I'm unsure whether it'd apply here. Thoughts?

Comment: No reason really, that's just the problem

Comment: The problem is that $\log X_i$ is distributed as $N(\theta, \theta)$ rather than $X_i$. I guess you could then let $ Y = \log X_i$ then $Y_i \sim N(\theta, \theta)$ and then it is treated pretty much the same way in terms of finding the MLE, but I wonder whether this affects the asymptotic distribution?

Comment: I see what you mean. I did not read the question correctly.

Comment: To answer your last question, it does not affect the asymptotic distribution. Why should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under certain regularity conditions (like the ones mentioned [here](http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/hallam/documents/Asymptotic_Dist.pdf) on page 1), maximum likelihood estimators have an asymptotic normal distribution. In particular, distributions which are members of the regular exponential family satisfy these conditions.

For $Y_i=\log X_i$, joint density of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ is

\begin{align}
f_{\theta}(y_1,\ldots,y_n)&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\theta\pi})^n}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta)^2\right]
\\&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\theta\pi})^n}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i-\frac{n\theta}{2}\right]\quad,\small (y_1,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb R^n,\,\theta>0
\end{align}

This shows that $f_{\theta}$ is a member of a regular one-parameter exponential family. So we can say that the MLE $\hat\theta$ of $\theta$ has an asymptotic normal distribution, given by

$$\sqrt n(\hat\theta-\theta)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N\left(0,\frac{1}{I_{Y_1}(\theta)}\right)\,,$$

where $I_{Y_1}(\theta)=-E_{\theta}\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\ln f_{\theta}(Y_1)\right]$ is the information contained in $Y_1$.

A routine calculation gives $I_{Y_1}(\theta)=\frac{2\theta+1}{2\theta^2}$, so that the limiting distribution is eventually

$$\sqrt n(\hat\theta-\theta)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N\left(0,\frac{2\theta^2}{2\theta+1}\right)$$

Comment: Hey, I've looked at a lot of statistics posts around here in the past few weeks and you seem to know a lot from what I've seen. Would you mind helping with this please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206737/umvue-of-px-1-%E2%89%A5-t-for-a-two-parameter-exponential-distribution ?